# NPM getting 404 trying to fetch @reach/router

Tags: reactjs, npm, gatsby

I'm trying to learn gatsbyjs, so when I use the gatsby-cli@2.4.3 to create a project, I cd in to the newly created directory and run `npm install`. Then it prints a 404 error trying to get the `@reach/router@1.2.0` package.

1. When I manually do `npm install --verbose @reach/router@1.2.0` I get this:

   ```
   npm info it worked if it ends with ok
   npm verb cli [ '/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/bin/node',
   npm verb cli   '/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/bin/npm',
   npm verb cli   'install',
   npm verb cli   '--verbose',
   npm verb cli   '@reach/router@1.2.0' ]
   npm info using npm@6.4.1
   npm info using node@v10.5.0
   npm verb npm-session 4a9d18b8df999ff8
   npm http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@reach%2frouter 2074ms
   npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
   npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 2180ms
   npm verb stack Error: 404 Not Found: @reach/router@1.2.0
   npm verb stack     at fetch.then.res (/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/pacote/lib/fetchers/registry/fetch.js:42:19)
   npm verb stack     at tryCatcher (/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
   npm verb stack     at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
   npm verb stack     at Promise._settlePromise (/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
   npm verb stack     at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
   npm verb stack     at Promise._settlePromises (/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:693:18)
   npm verb stack     at Async._drainQueue (/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
   npm verb stack     at Async._drainQueues (/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
   npm verb stack     at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
   npm verb stack     at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
   npm verb stack     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
   npm verb stack     at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
   npm verb cwd /home/matfau/dev/realtraining-gatsby
   npm verb Linux 4.15.0-38-generic
   npm verb argv "/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/bin/node" "/home/matfau/.nvm/versions/node/v10.5.0/bin/npm" "install" "--verbose" "@reach/router@1.2.0"
   npm verb node v10.5.0
   npm verb npm  v6.4.1
   npm ERR! code E404
   npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @reach/router@1.2.0
   npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
   npm timing npm Completed in 2403ms

   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /home/matfau/.npm/_logs/2018-10-21T20_28_35_069Z-debug.log
   ```
2. When I try to curl the package with `curl -sD - https://registry.npmjs.org/@reach%2frouter -o /dev/null` I get this:

   ```
   HTTP/2 200 
   date: Sun, 21 Oct 2018 20:34:19 GMT
   content-type: application/json
   set-cookie: __cfduid=d77c28ce2e70e2ae3525fb54f39f20e3c1540154057; expires=Mon, 21-Oct-19 20:34:17 GMT; path=/; domain=.registry.npmjs.org; HttpOnly
   age: 899341
   cf-ray: 46d6810d3ee842b5-OSL
   etag: W/"4bd43800e5b915de556ca0740caf5d47"
   expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
   last-modified: Tue, 25 Sep 2018 16:59:20 GMT
   vary: Accept, Accept-Encoding
   via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.2)
   x-amz-meta-rev: 20-12439c265d175add79de2380a5d8c405
   x-varnish: 159054570 105803757
   server: cloudflare
   ```
3. So, I'm able to curl the package endpoint, but npm cannot. Why? Well, it could be something wrong with the registry endpoint but it's not that either. `npm config get registry` gives me `https://registry.npmjs.org/`
4. I've tried to delete npm caches with the --force flag, delete the node_modules directory. I've also tried with yarn, and it stops at the very same package.
5. Other packages work fine, for instance if I do `npm install jquery` then I get no errors.
6. I have another computer where this exact same process works just fine, with the same version of NPM. So I know that the problem is on my computer, but I have no idea what else to check for.

Question is, why do I get the 404 error, and what I can check to debug this problem further?

Comment: First, make sure you got latest `npm` by `$ npm install npm@latest -g`. It might be a temporary networking issue too.

Comment: I'm using `nvm`, but I have tried using both the latest version of `npm` as well as different older versions. I got the 404 error with all versions.

If this is a network related issue, then how do you explain the result from the curl command above? I don't think networking is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Today I tried again for the 4th or 5th day in a row, with the same npm version as listed above and suddenly it just works. At least now I'm able to continue my quest to learn gatsby, but coming from the Maven universe this kind of magic behaviour scares me a little.

Answer (score 0):

I ran `npm login` and created a username and password, and that fixed the reach router problem.